# Cannot Update.Database or object is read only[Error 3027]

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I'm facing problem when i tried to delete data from database.I'm using Access Database

```
strqry3 = "SELECT * " & _
"FROM ((tbl_l0_est INNER JOIN tbl_project_resource_matrix ON    
tbl_l0_est.pr_matrix_key = tbl_project_resource_matrix.pr_matrix_key) INNER JOIN 
tbl_proj_app_impacted ON tbl_project_resource_matrix.project_key =  
tbl_proj_app_impacted.project_key)  " & _
"WHERE app_impacted = '" & Text & "'"

Set rst3 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strqry3)

If rst3.EOF = True Then
'MsgBox ("")

Else
Do Until rst3.EOF
rst3.Delete
rst3.MoveNext
Loop
End If
```

[image: Error]

Please Advise

Answer (score 0):

The fact is that you cant delete records in that way (calling .delete method) from a composte SELECT. That is valid only in `select * from onlyOneTable where some=condition`

The same even occurs with other databases using for example ADO .delete method, which fails. The reason is that is no clear to the RDBM to which table .delete refers to.